# Ansible parsing lists inside dictionary

Tags: list, dictionary, parsing, ansible

```
- name: Use Collections
  hosts: all
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/local/bin/python3.9 


  tasks:
        - name: Collect BIG-IP information
          bigip_device_info:
           gather_subset:
            - virtual-servers
           provider:
            server: y.y.y.y
            user: abc
            password: abc1
            validate_certs: False
          delegate_to: localhost
          register: output

        - name: debug
          debug: msg={{output.ansible_facts| json_query(jmesquery)}}
          vars:
             jmesquery: "[*].{Satus: item.availability_status, Destinationaddress: item.destination_address, Destination: item.destination}"
```

i am getting below output, empty message

```
ansible-playbook -i inv bigipfacts.yml

PLAY [Use Collections] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Collect BIG-IP information] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [y.y.y.y]

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [y.y.y.y] => {
    "msg": ""
}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
y.y.y.y                 : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Required/wanted output- in future i want parse more from bottom output. but for now these three values.

```
"availability_status": "available",                
"destination": "/1.1.1..1:8080",
"destination_address": "2.2.2.2",

"availability_status": "available",
"destination": "/3.3.3.3.3%22:8080",
"destination_address": "4.4.4.4",
```

output.ansible_facts has below info, i want to parse below output and extract only few values in a list like shown above

```
TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [x.x.x.x] => {
    "msg": {
        "ansible_net_queried": true,
        "ansible_net_virtual_servers": [
            {
                "auto_lasthop": "default",
                "availability_status": "available",
                "client_side_bits_in": 0,
                "client_side_bits_out": 0,
                "client_side_current_connections": 0,
                "client_side_evicted_connections": 0,
                "client_side_max_connections": 0,
                "client_side_pkts_in": 0,
                "client_side_pkts_out": 0,
                "client_side_slow_killed": 0,
                "client_side_total_connections": 0,
                "cmp_enabled": "yes",
                "cmp_mode": "all-cpus",
                "connection_limit": 0,
                "connection_mirror_enabled": "no",
                "cpu_usage_ratio_last_1_min": 0,
                "cpu_usage_ratio_last_5_min": 0,
                "cpu_usage_ratio_last_5_sec": 0,
                "current_syn_cache": 0,
                "default_pool": "/POOL01",
                "destination": "/1.1.1..1:8080",
                "destination_address": "2.2.2.2",
                "destination_port": 8080,
                "enabled": "no",
                "ephemeral_bits_in": 0,
                "ephemeral_bits_out": 0,
                "ephemeral_current_connections": 0,
                "ephemeral_evicted_connections": 0,
                "ephemeral_max_connections": 0,
                "ephemeral_pkts_in": 0,
                "ephemeral_pkts_out": 0,
                "ephemeral_slow_killed": 0,
                "ephemeral_total_connections": 0,
                "full_path": "/p1/VS01",
                "gtm_score": 0,
                "hardware_syn_cookie_instances": 0,
                "max_conn_duration": 0,
                "mean_conn_duration": 0,
                "min_conn_duration": 0,
                "name": "vs01",
                "nat64_enabled": "no",
                "profiles": [
                    {
                        "context": "all",
                        "full_path": "/Common/http",
                        "name": "http"
                    },
                    {
                        "context": "all",
                        "full_path": "/Common/oneconnect",
                        "name": "oneconnect"
                    },
                    {
                        "context": "all",
                        "full_path": "/Common/tcp",
                        "name": "tcp"
                    }
                ],
                "protocol": "tcp",
                "rate_limit": -1,
                "rate_limit_destination_mask": 0,
                "rate_limit_mode": "object",
                "rate_limit_source_mask": 0,
                "snat_type": "automap",
                "software_syn_cookie_instances": 0,
                "source_address": "0.0.0.0%22/0",
                "source_port_behavior": "preserve",
                "status_reason": "The virtual server is available",
                "syn_cache_overflow": 0,
                "syn_cookies_status": "not-activated",
                "total_hardware_accepted_syn_cookies": 0,
                "total_hardware_syn_cookies": 0,
                "total_requests": 0,
                "total_software_accepted_syn_cookies": 0,
                "total_software_rejected_syn_cookies": 0,
                "total_software_syn_cookies": 0,
                "translate_address": "yes",
                "translate_port": "yes",
                "type": "standard",
                "vlans": [
                    "/Common/vlans"
                ]
            },
            {
                "auto_lasthop": "default",
                "availability_status": "available",
                "client_side_bits_in": 0,
                "client_side_bits_out": 0,
                "client_side_current_connections": 0,
                "client_side_evicted_connections": 0,
                "client_side_max_connections": 0,
                "client_side_pkts_in": 0,
                "client_side_pkts_out": 0,
                "client_side_slow_killed": 0,
                "client_side_total_connections": 0,
                "cmp_enabled": "yes",
                "cmp_mode": "all-cpus",
                "connection_limit": 0,
                "connection_mirror_enabled": "no",
                "cpu_usage_ratio_last_1_min": 0,
                "cpu_usage_ratio_last_5_min": 0,
                "cpu_usage_ratio_last_5_sec": 0,
                "current_syn_cache": 0,
                "default_pool": "/POOL01",
                "destination": "/3.3.3.3.3%22:8080",
                "destination_address": "4.4.4.4",
                "destination_port": 8080,
                "enabled": "no",
                "ephemeral_bits_in": 0,
                "ephemeral_bits_out": 0,
                "ephemeral_current_connections": 0,
                "ephemeral_evicted_connections": 0,
                "ephemeral_max_connections": 0,
                "ephemeral_pkts_in": 0,
                "ephemeral_pkts_out": 0,
                "ephemeral_slow_killed": 0,
                "ephemeral_total_connections": 0,
                "full_path": "/p1/VS01",
                "gtm_score": 0,
                "hardware_syn_cookie_instances": 0,
                "max_conn_duration": 0,
                "mean_conn_duration": 0,
                "min_conn_duration": 0,
                "name": "vs02",
                "nat64_enabled": "no",
                "profiles": [
                    {
                        "context": "all",
                        "full_path": "/Common/http",
                        "name": "http"
                    },
                    {
                        "context": "all",
                        "full_path": "/Common/oneconnect",
                        "name": "oneconnect"
                    },
                    {
                        "context": "all",
                        "full_path": "/Common/tcp",
                        "name": "tcp"
                    }
                ],
                "protocol": "tcp",
                "rate_limit": -1,
                "rate_limit_destination_mask": 0,
                "rate_limit_mode": "object",
                "rate_limit_source_mask": 0,
                "snat_type": "automap",
                "software_syn_cookie_instances": 0,
                "source_address": "0.0.0.0%22/0",
                "source_port_behavior": "preserve",
                "status_reason": "The virtual server is available",
                "syn_cache_overflow": 0,
                "syn_cookies_status": "not-activated",
                "total_hardware_accepted_syn_cookies": 0,
                "total_hardware_syn_cookies": 0,
                "total_requests": 0,
                "total_software_accepted_syn_cookies": 0,
                "total_software_rejected_syn_cookies": 0,
                "total_software_syn_cookies": 0,
                "translate_address": "yes",
                "translate_port": "yes",
                "type": "standard",
                "vlans": [
                    "/Common/vlan"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You omitted `ansible_net_virtual_servers` entirely, and appear to have conflated `with_items:` (which sets an `item` name in jinja2) with JMESPath which has no such implicit name creation

```yaml
  - debug:
      msg: >-
        {{ output.ansible_facts.ansible_net_virtual_servers
        | json_query(jmesquery) }}
    vars:
      jmesquery: "[*].{Satus: availability_status, Destinationaddress: destination_address, Destination: destination}"
```

produces

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "Destination": "/1.1.1..1:8080",
            "Destinationaddress": "2.2.2.2",
            "Satus": "available"
        },
        {
            "Destination": "/3.3.3.3.3%22:8080",
            "Destinationaddress": "4.4.4.4",
            "Satus": "available"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: i tried above but i am getting values as null
`
ok: [1host] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "Destination": null,
            "Satus": null
        },
        {
            "Destination": null,
            "Satus": null
        },
        {
`

Comment: my bad, i had a typo in the script. Thank you for your suggestion.